# What characters should I use or not use in usernames on Linux?

Tags: linux, user-accounts

I want to create user accounts named after a domain name. adduser complains that the usernames need to match the `NAME_REGEX` regular expression.

```
adduser: Please enter a username matching the regular expression configured
via the NAME_REGEX configuration variable.  Use the `--force-badname'
option to relax this check or reconfigure NAME_REGEX.
```

I can add the users using useradd without complaint. 
Is there a reason that I shouldn't modify the regular expression to allow `.`, `-` and `_`?

What characters will cause problems and shouldn't be allowed in usernames?

This is the default `NAME_REGEX`.

```
NAME_REGEX="^[a-z][-a-z0-9]*\$"
```

Comment: Note that `NAME_REGEX` already accepts `-` as long as it's not the first character.

Comment: Why not add `.`?

Consider a user named `.` or `..`.  Then, `rm` that user named `..`.

Comment: @Jon that's not an issue since `rm` is not the command to use when deleting a user. I agree `..` is not a sensible name for similar reasons, but `rm` is not one of those.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

My advice to you is to follow the standard recommended by the default NAME_REGEX.  You can actually put nearly anything in a user name under *NIX but you may encounter odd problems with library code that makes assumptions.  Case in point:

https://web.archive.org/web/20170928165345/http://blog.endpoint.com/2008/08/on-valid-unix-usernames-and-ones-sanity.html

My question to you: do you have a lot of domain names that would collide with each other if you stripped out the unusual punctuation?  For example, do you have both "QUALITY-ASSURANCE" and QUALITYASSURANCE" as domain names?  If not, you could simply adopt a policy of stripping out the unusual characters and using what's left as the user name.

Also, you could use the "real name" section of the [GECOS field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field) in the /etc/passwd information to store the original, unmodified domain name, and scripts could extract it pretty easily.

Comment: It is the running into random unexpected bugs part that I'm worried about. I can pretty easily remove the periods and still have no chance of name clashes, but the - could cause a problem. Still it is pretty unlikely.

Comment: So the debian system I'm using is using a user www-data. So it looks like - should be ok to be used in usernames.

Comment: Actually, that regular expression permits '-' in user names!  The first letter needs to be a-z, but subsequent letters of the user names can be '-', a-z, or 0-9.

Comment: Ohh! you're right. I missed the extra - when i was looking at it.

Answer (score 44):

More specifically, the [POSIX ("Portable Operating System Interface for Unix") standard (IEEE Standard 1003.1 2008) states](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/):

---

[3.437 User Name](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_437)

> A string that is used to identify a user; see also User Database. To be portable across systems conforming to POSIX.1-2017, the value is composed of characters from the portable filename character set. The `<hyphen-minus>` character should not be used as the first character of a portable user name.

---

[3.282 Portable Filename Character Set](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_282)

```
The set of characters from which portable filenames are constructed.

A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 . _ -
```

---

Any username that complies with this standard is POSIX-compliant, and ought to be safe.

Comment: While this is true it's generally frowned upon to have upper-case characters in usernames - people have enough trouble with case-sensitive passwords, and making them have to remember case in their usernames is just kicking them when they're down. (Exception: When your username convention is `ALL UPPERCASE CHARACTERS`.)

Comment: As of POSIX.1-2017, those definitions have moved a bit.

3.431 User Name is now [3.437 User Name](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_437) and 3.278 Portable Filename Character Set is now [3.282 Portable Filename Character Set](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_282)

Comment: @voretaq7  What I think is legit is to *preserve* case in a username, but make sign-ins case-insensitive.  So a username could be CatInTheHat but sign in specifying catinthehat or catintheHAT or whatever.

Comment: So, if we have a user `FOO` and a user `foo`, and I come around and try to sign in as "Foo"... what happens?

Comment: That would be an invalid username.

Comment: Case-folding obviously also needs to happen when checking for an already existing user.

Comment: Case folding would be a bad thing.  This is from the time when you had terminals with all uppercase and no lower case characters.  So you would not be able to distinguish between upper case and lower case user name.
So the rule of thumb is user name (and group name) should be maximum 8 characters long, and only lower case characters. Start with a character and then also allow `-` and digits.
But yes, you can have a `.`, but that would be a problem for `chown(1)`, for instance, as it uses `.` to separate user name and group name.

Comment: There are other troublesome characters, like `:`.  And why, look at man page `passwd(5)` and `shadow(5)`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is a reason behind this limitation.

If you try to run `systemd(1)` service for scripts, it can be starting as `root` and not as an ordinary user. It's caused by `systemd` not recognize user with dot (`domain.com` user name for example) as valid user and runs service as `root` instead. Still this can be already fixed on `systemd` side, but still has a risk.

Also having dots in the user name creates some issues with scripts using
`chown(1)`, which accepts dots as separator between user name and
group name, see man page for `chown(1)` on the system, to identify is it legacy or modernized version. In older systems, there could be scripts using this notation, which will break if a user name contains a dot.

Comment: The `chown(1)` argument that is separate user and group names with a `.` is valid.

But there are some rules of thumb that you also should apply.  Like many programs supposes that the user name have maximum length of 8 characters.  You can have longer names, but you should not.
Also login names usually are restricted to lower case characters. But you still can have upper case characters in user namn.

Same applies to group names.

Comment: This is historical issue. Previous versions of the chown utility used the dot (".") character to distinguish the group name. This has been changed to be a colon (":") character, so that user and group names may contain the dot character.

Answer (score 0):

From the NAME_REGEX can be deduced that everything but a through z in upper- and lowercase and the number 0 through 9 would be bad.

Comment: The word you're looking for is "deduced".

Comment: look at the regex again, `-` is also accepted (just not as the first character.)  Also note that by default uppercase is not accepted (there is no `g` flag, nor is `A-Z` included in the`NAME_REGEX`  regex provided by the OP. `NAME_REGEX="^[a-z][-a-z0-9]*\$"`

Comment: @SherylHohman You actually meant "there is no `i` flag...", I suppose.

Comment: @JensMoser, lol, yes I did. Thanks.