# Can I use an email username as a SAMBA username?

Tags: linux, samba, samba4

I get this error when I try this command

sudo smbldap-useradd -a -m -P ram@chroots.com
/usr/sbin/smbldap-useradd
: illegal username

Is there a way to get an email as username, what should I be doing.

Answer (score 2):

`smbldap-useradd` creates regular Linux users in an LDAP directory and adds the required fields to also make it a valid samba user (this is likely not compatible with Samba4 AD support). Since for Linux, [unlike Windows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726984.aspx), `@` characters are not [really supported](https://serverfault.com/a/578264/8897) in usernames, 
the tool wisely rejects such a username.

You likely could add non-POSIX samba users to your LDAP directory with other tools, but they obviously wouldn't be integrated with Linux. If you care for this integration, don't use mail addresses as user names.