# exim4 sends wrong Mail From header

Tags: exim, smtp-headers

When I send an email via my smtp exim4 server, I get this error:

`The sender address blah@usersdomain@myserver.net is not\n553 5.1.2 a valid RFC-5321 address.`

Logins to the server are with full email address. But exim4 just concatenates the user login with my primary_hostname to get this debacle. How can I change this?

Comment: `@` isn't a valid character in a Unix user name. [source](http://serverfault.com/questions/73084/what-characters-should-i-use-or-not-use-in-usernames-on-linux/)

Comment: That was the issue. But I'll post the answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is:

```
acl_check_rcpt:
  ... your stuff here, then abit later towards the end of the ACL
  accept  
    authenticated = *
    # JolieRouge This took some time to search out
    # 2006-09-27 <pille@struction.de>
    # force empty domain, when fixing header during submission, as we use fqdn in our usernames (to avoid doubled domains)
    # 2007-01-30 <pille@struction.de>
    # added /sender_retain option to take any given address from 'Sender:'-header (used as 'Return-path:' and for 'MAIL FROM:'-SMTP-command)
    control       = submission/sender_retain/domain=
```

The bottom line `control = submission/sender_retain/domain=` is used when your logins are a full email address.